# Converting to predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I having a lot of trouble converting two english statements to predicate logic:

1. For every positive real number x, there is some real number y that is the square
   root of x (extend this statement to show that there are two distinct
   square roots of x)
2. For any two distinct real numbers there is a third real number with a value between the first two.

I figured out the first part of the first statement : ∀x (x > 0 → ∃y (y=$\sqrt{x}$)) but I am unable to solve the second part (extend this statement to show that there are two distinct square roots of x)

and I am clueless how to go about the second question (For any two distinct real numbers...)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I give you a hint:

You can reformulate the parenthesized sentence into: For any positive real $x$ there exist numbers $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that they are not equal and such that each of them is a square root of $x$.
I would write "$y$ being a square root of $x$" as $y^2=x$, since $\sqrt{x}$ is not unique in your statement.

For the second part: For any two $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are not equal there exists $y$ such that ($x_1$ is smaller than $y$ and $y$ is smaller than $x_2$) or ($x_2$ is smaller than $y$ and $y$ is smaller than $x_1$).

Is it clear to you why these are the same?

Comment: I think so... thank you